# Movie with Alien or Orc Creatures, Bred for Violence Scene

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, orcs

This is driving me crazy, because I know I've gotten wires crossed in my head. A lot of the scene has been mixed with the Uruk-Hai spawning scene in Lord of the Rings, which I've rewatched and it doesn't match (unless it's some deleted scene?)

I watched this probably in the last 5-6 years. Full color, live-action.

- A manager/master/leader is walking through a spawning area for some sort of Orcs or Aliens (Again, wires crossed.)
- He's describing the advancements made with the new breed. They're violent, aggressive, and have no fear.
- One of them wakes up, and grabs one of the breeders (by the neck?)
- The leader dispatches (gun? axe?) the newly spawned creature, saying "That one was a little ***too*** aggressive." (violent? fearless? dominant?)

It's beyond me how I really feel like these are aliens of some kind (reavers or something?) but I can almost see the whole scene with Saruman.

**Edits:**

- The aliens are humanoid
- They are being bred to stop the heroes/advance the villains crusade
- The breeder may have been some sort of contract labor? Mercenary? Mad science for hire?
- Rewatching the Uruk-Hai scene from LOTR, it's essentially the same scene-But they're some kind of sci-fi humanoid, and the leader sees the excessive aggression as a negative trait (Where Saruman was pleased with it)
- The leader is not as upset about the excessive aggression, but the disrespect for authority. That particular spawn would be hard to control.
- Maybe this was a video game cutscene if nobody remembers it right away?

Comment: I assume from what you've written this is set in either the modern age or the future?

Comment: "*I, uh, guess I made them a little too aggressive, huh?*" - Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles: Escape from the Planet of the Turtleoids (1993) - https://turtlepedia.fandom.com/wiki/Planet_of_the_Turtleoids,_Part_1

Comment: @Nu'Daq I've really conflated this scene with LOTR in my head. I seem to remember it's a sci-fi movie, set in the future. Genetically Engineer/Cross Bred/Cloned killing machines. But it might just be a deleted scene from LOTR.

Comment: @Valorum That's the right spirit of the scene, generally.